# ktor client post request causes error `lateinit property nextElementName has not been initialized`

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'm trying to use ktor to make a simple post requests to a remote API. There's a single endpoint, and the request and response body is in JSON.

I'm using

- ktor 2.0.1
- Kotlin 1.6.21
- Kotlinx Serialization 1.3.2
- Kotlin Coroutines 1.6.1

The endpoint I need to POST to is `https://mods.factorio.com/api/v2/mods/releases/init_upload` - [details here](https://wiki.factorio.com/Mod_upload_API).

I've created a client

```kotlin
private val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
  install(Resources)
  install(Logging) {
    logger = Logger.DEFAULT
    level = LogLevel.HEADERS
  }
  install(ContentNegotiation) {
    json(Json {
      prettyPrint = true
      isLenient = true
    })
  }
  defaultRequest {
    header(HttpHeaders.Authorization, "Bearer 123")
  }
  followRedirects = false
  expectSuccess = true
}
```

and I use it to make a post request

```kotlin
  val response = client.post(portalUploadEndpoint) {
    contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
    setBody(InitUploadRequest("123"))
  }
```

The request and response body are JSON objects, and I'm using Kotlinx Serialization. (See the full code at the bottom of this question.)

However I get an error. Am I doing something wrong?

```
Exception in thread "main" kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property nextElementName has not been initialized
    at io.ktor.resources.serialization.ParametersEncoder.encodeValue(ParametersEncoder.kt:26)
    at kotlinx.serialization.encoding.AbstractEncoder.encodeString(AbstractEncoder.kt:51)
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.StringSerializer.serialize(Primitives.kt:141)
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.StringSerializer.serialize(Primitives.kt:138)
    at kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Encoder$DefaultImpls.encodeSerializableValue(Encoding.kt:282)
    at kotlinx.serialization.encoding.AbstractEncoder.encodeSerializableValue(AbstractEncoder.kt:18)
    at io.ktor.resources.serialization.ResourcesFormat.encodeToParameters(ResourcesFormat.kt:90)
    at io.ktor.resources.UrlBuilderKt.href(UrlBuilder.kt:49)
    at MainKt$main$1.invokeSuspend(main.kt:163)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:279)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at MainKt.main(main.kt:47)
    at MainKt.main(main.kt)
```

#### full code

```kotlin
import io.ktor.client.HttpClient
import io.ktor.client.engine.cio.CIO
import io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.ContentNegotiation
import io.ktor.client.plugins.defaultRequest
import io.ktor.client.plugins.logging.DEFAULT
import io.ktor.client.plugins.logging.LogLevel
import io.ktor.client.plugins.logging.Logger
import io.ktor.client.plugins.logging.Logging
import io.ktor.client.plugins.resources.Resources
import io.ktor.client.plugins.resources.post
import io.ktor.client.request.header
import io.ktor.client.request.setBody
import io.ktor.http.ContentType
import io.ktor.http.HttpHeaders
import io.ktor.http.URLBuilder
import io.ktor.http.contentType
import io.ktor.http.takeFrom
import io.ktor.resources.Resource
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.json
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer
import kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonElement
import kotlinx.serialization.json.jsonObject


private val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
  install(Resources)
  install(Logging) {
    logger = Logger.DEFAULT
    level = LogLevel.HEADERS
  }
  install(ContentNegotiation) {
    json(Json {
      prettyPrint = true
      isLenient = true
    })
  }
  defaultRequest {
    header(HttpHeaders.Authorization, "Bearer 123")
  }
  followRedirects = false
  expectSuccess = true
}

fun main() = runBlocking {

  val apiBase = "https://mods.factorio.com/api/v2"
  val uploadEndpoint = "mods/releases/"

  val portalUploadEndpoint = URLBuilder(apiBase).apply {
    takeFrom(uploadEndpoint)
  }.buildString()

  println(portalUploadEndpoint)

  val response = client.post(portalUploadEndpoint) {
    contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
    setBody(InitUploadRequest("123"))
  }

  println(response)
}

@Resource("/init_upload")
@Serializable
data class InitUploadRequest(
  @SerialName("mod") val modName: String,
)


@Serializable(with = InitUploadResponse.Serializer::class)
sealed interface InitUploadResponse {

  /**
   * @param[uploadUrl] URL the mod zip file should be uploaded to
   */
  @Serializable
  data class Success(
    @SerialName("upload_url") val uploadUrl: String,
  ) : InitUploadResponse

  object Serializer :
    JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<InitUploadResponse>(InitUploadResponse::class) {
    override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement) = when {
      "upload_url" in element.jsonObject -> Success.serializer()
      else                               -> Failure.serializer()
    }
  }
}

@Serializable
data class Failure(
  val error: String? = null,
  val message: String? = null,
) : InitUploadResponse
```

#### See also

I've also report this on YouTrack https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-4342/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@aleksei-tirman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13963150/aleksei-tirman) for pointing out that there are two extension functions in Ktor that cause this confusion.

- [`io.ktor.client.request.post`](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/io.ktor.client.request/post.html)
- [`io.ktor.client.plugins.resources.post`](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-client/ktor-client-plugins/ktor-client-resources/io.ktor.client.plugins.resources/post.html)

These can clash - so make sure you use the correct one.

There was an additional problem that I've also resolved. I originally said

> The request and response body are JSON objects

The requests are actually form parameters.

Instead of

```kotlin
  val response = client.post(portalUploadEndpoint) {
    contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
    setBody(InitUploadRequest("123"))
  }
```

I changed it to

```kotlin
  val response = client.submitForm(
      url = portalUploadEndpoint,
      formParameters = Parameters.build {
        append("mod", modName)
      }
    )
```

The response is a JSON body, which I manually decode

```kotlin
    val initUploadResponse: InitUploadResponse =
      Json.decodeFromString(InitUploadResponse.serializer(), response.bodyAsText())
```

I then removed the `Resources` Ktor plugin from the `HttpClient` - it's not needed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're passing a `String` (URL) to the `HttpClient.post` extension function that expects a `Resource`. You need to pass a [resource](https://ktor.io/docs/type-safe-request.html) there or use the `HttpClient.post` extension function from the `io.ktor.client.request` package.

Comment: Using the `io.ktor.client.request.post` extension results in `Invalid TLS record type code: 72`.

Comment: And that's the https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-4281. The fix will be released in Ktor 2.0.2.